# Why do I get different results when launching a shell script from automator or AppleScript than when launching from the terminal?

Tags: bash, electron, applescript, automator

I have a simple script to launch an electron app using NPM.

```
npm start --prefix /Users/thinkdigital/development/github/ytmdesktop/ &
disown %$(jobs | grep ytmdesktop | cut -c 2)
```

Since I want to save this in the dock as a launcher, I tried running this process from many different places.

- A Dart script
- Automator
- Apple Script

Each time it runs the command, other than from the shell, it doesn't launch the application. In fact, when launching from Dart, I do get this in stderr.

> Cannot read property 'app' of undefined
>       at new ElectronStore....

Is there something I need to do to get this script to function when launched from anywhere except directly through the terminal?

Comment: When using AppleScript's `do shell script` command try adding `/usr/local/bin/`, _(i.e. the default location for npm)_, to your `PATH` variable prior to running your given compound command. For instance: `do shell script "PATH=" & quoted form of "/usr/local/bin/:$PATH" & " npm start --prefix /Users/thinkdigital/development/github/ytmdesktop/ & disown %$(jobs | grep ytmdesktop | cut -c 2)"`

Comment: @RobC, You shouldn't use `quoted form of` around a _variable_ as it stops it from expanding. If you run `do shell script "PATH=" & quoted form of "/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; echo $PATH"` it returns `""`. If you run `do shell script "PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; echo $PATH"` it returns: `"/usr/local/bin/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`

Comment: **Edit:** Example provided in my earlier comment should be the following instead: `do shell script "PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; npm start --prefix /Users/thinkdigital/development/github/ytmdesktop/ & disown %$(jobs | grep ytmdesktop | cut -c 2)"`

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to Dart, but you should be aware that `do shell script` in AppleScript and `Run Shell Script` actions in Automator workflows don't load the configuration files that normally get loaded when you open a shell in Terminal. In particular, the default `PATH` variable is stripped down — "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin" — and doesn't include "/usr/local/bin" where `npm` is located (assuming it's still in the default location; run `which npm` in Terminal to make sure).

Try using the full path to npm and see if that solves your problem:

```
/usr/local/bin/npm start --prefix /Users/thinkdigital/development/github/ytmdesktop/ & disown %$(jobs | grep ytmdesktop | cut -c 2)
```